# How to use must use plugin in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Friends,
 I know this question asked before but i cannot find them . I want to move all plugin in to must use directory.

In wordpress blog also have answer but i can't understand them .

Any one suggest link to use must use plugin for all plugin

Comment: What is your question? Are you having problems moving the plugins to the must-use directory or you can't find the must-use folder?

Comment: i moved all plugin in to must use directory but it not showing in must use plugin section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mu-plugins directory will not read plugins in a subfolder, so all plugins must be individual files (as per "plugin-name.php" file).

This main plugin file is what will include additional files that exist in a subdirectory. Any plugin files in a subfolder will be ignored unless included in the primary plugin file.